# Preventing the pager less from exiting when scrolling beyond the end of file

Tags: linux, less, pager

I like [less](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Less_%28Unix%29) and use it as my default pager in Linux.

However, there are times that I am scrolling down through a large document quickly and less  exits when I reach the end of the document before I have time to stop scrolling. I'd like `less` to exit only I type `q`, and not because I ask it to scroll beyond the end of the document. Is that possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pass `-+e -+E` to `less` to disable quit-at-EOF.

Comment: You can also set your `LESS` environment variable for any flags you want to set for all invocations.

Comment: A sidenote: if you experience the same problem with `zless`, setting `LESS` env variable does not help if `zless` is – quite counter-intuitively – using `more` as the pager. If that's the case, set `PAGER=/usr/bin/less`.